# copyto Google Sheets Script adding date and source data in the next column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to Javascript and Apps Script. I want to create a function that updates another sheet based on a date in a certain range of the active sheet. I run and no error but it doesn't transfer value from active sheet to sheet named "January", in different target url google sheet

[data master post](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQ93ylP0MHzSzxH0myS9_AhTjetdvLQMXvFwg18XFEE/edit#gid=0)

[output 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ShPxDW9qhz4aWgaQ1G9oz7w1yh0-Wfe2VItet95UYks/edit?usp=sharing)

[output 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Dx3ZOpV7baSTadSApIrVVccN-bHrPlHu240Aux0fo0/edit?usp=sharing)

[output 3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14EVlqaP1ilXwopgi0ESvp_IKkSyROSF22WzWAcNAJWc/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function myFunction4() {
const spreadsheetIds = [
{ id: "1ShPxDW9qhz4aWgaQ1G9oz7w1yh0-Wfe2VItet95UYks", sheetNames: 
["cab1"] },
{ id: "13Dx3ZOpV7baSTadSApIrVVccN-bHrPlHu240Aux0fo0", sheetNames: 
["cab2"] },
{ id: "14EVlqaP1ilXwopgi0ESvp_IKkSyROSF22WzWAcNAJWc", sheetNames: 
["cab3", "cab4"] }
];

const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("January");
if (!srcSheet) return;
const date = new Date();
const ssName = srcSpreadsheet.getName();
const range = srcSheet.getRange("A2:C" + srcSheet.getLastRow());
let values = range.getValues();
if (values.filter(r => r.join("")).length == 0) return;
values = values.map(r => [...r, date, ssName]);
range.clearContent();
for (let i = 0; i < spreadsheetIds.length; i++) {
const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIds[i].id);
for (let j = 0; j < spreadsheetIds[i].sheetNames.length; j++) {
  const targetSheet = 
dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheetIds[i].sheetNames[j]);
  if (targetSheet) {
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, 
  values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

copyto Google Sheets Script adding date and source data in the next column

[sample video](https://youtu.be/fef6FI5CpG0)

[which is desired](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qfc1Bd0ykFiCySc8yuwMnlJrc1t7scbg/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117593148699594556587&rtpof=true&sd=true)

I want when I click the send button.
can add Date and source in the next column

Date = date when sent

source = the name of the workbook that sent it

```
    otherSheetName.getRange(1,getJumlahKolom+1).setValue("Date").setFontWeight("bold").setHorizontalAlignment("center");  
    otherSheetName.getRange(1,getJumlahKolom+2).setValue("source").setFontWeight("bold").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
```

Date & source, the function you want to join to myFunction3()

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your sample Spreadsheets and your showing script and "sample video" and your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Tanaike
im update

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your question, you say `but it doesn't transfer value from active sheet to sheet named "January"`. But, in your added sample, it seems that the values from the "January" sheet of Spreadsheet "A" is copied to "cab1" sheet of Spreadsheet "B". And, in your added script, "January" sheet is not used. As the result, what is your actual expected result? I'm confused. I apologize for this.

Comment: try click send button

Comment: Date & source, the function you want to join to myFunction3() . 
Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of `Date & source, the function you want to join to myFunction3().`?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qfc1Bd0ykFiCySc8yuwMnlJrc1t7scbg/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117593148699594556587&rtpof=true&sd=true

word file for detail .Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your document, it seems that the situation of your document is different from your provided saple spreadsheet. But, for example, if you want to copy the value of "input" sheet to "Master" and add 2 columns of "Date" and "source" to the same row, when I click the button on your Spreadsheet, it seems that it has already been achieved. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: "Date" dan "source"   tanaike, can you modify on myFunction3()

Comment: getRange(1,getJumlahKolom+1).setValue("Date") & getRange(1,getJumlahKolom+2).setValue("source")

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve your goal by modifying your showing script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction3() {
  const spreadsheetIds = [
    { id: "1aUoRKCnztsZAvbMwSa8Zk-gB-zfn1KeQnJgWIGRVu24", sheetNames: ["cab1"] },
    { id: "1Eme5Rb9_5kbGaT-HTy5ThR1WYUeR1fkQbn2-8wY-uUY", sheetNames: ["cab2"] },
    { id: "150DduDdhFJLC0LL7iOihYa6V1vaZckvtRxJUqCFFV9Q", sheetNames: ["cab3", "cab4"] }
  ];

  const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("input");
  if (!srcSheet) return;
  const date = new Date();
  const ssName = srcSpreadsheet.getName();
  const range = srcSheet.getRange("A2:C" + srcSheet.getLastRow());
  let values = range.getValues();
  if (values.filter(r => r.join("")).length == 0) return;
  values = values.map(r => [...r, date, ssName]);
  range.clearContent();
  for (let i = 0; i < spreadsheetIds.length; i++) {
    const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIds[i].id);
    for (let j = 0; j < spreadsheetIds[i].sheetNames.length; j++) {
      const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheetIds[i].sheetNames[j]);
      if (targetSheet) {
        targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the source sheet, and the retrieved values are put to the destination sheet by adding 2 columns of date and source.

#### Note:

- Please confirm the source and destination sheet names again. Because it seems that the sheet names of your showing script are different from your sample.

Comment: source = sheet names , yes

Comment: otherSheetName.getRange(1,getJumlahKolom+1).setValue("Date").setFontWeight("bold").setHorizontalAlignment("center");

Comment: otherSheetName.getRange(1,getJumlahKolom+2).setValue("source").setFontWeight("bold").setHorizontalAlignment("center");

Comment: sorry if I don't understand. if my english is wrong

Comment: @dra Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your replies, do you want to set the bold and the center text alignment to all rows of the columns "D" and "E"?

Comment: @dra If my understanding is correct, please modify `targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);` to `targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values).offset(0, 3).setFontWeight("bold").setHorizontalAlignment("center");` and test it again.

Comment: modify the code according to Tanaike
 . If something doesn't fit, I'll ask again.

Comment: sorry im finis edit code function myFunction4() {
const spreadsheetIds = [
{ id: "1ShPxDW9qhz4aWgaQ1G9oz7w1yh0-Wfe2VItet95UYks", sheetNames: 
["cab1"] }, (wrong start)

Comment: @dra Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `sorry im finis edit code function myFunction4() { const spreadsheetIds = [ { id: "1ShPxDW9qhz4aWgaQ1G9oz7w1yh0-Wfe2VItet95UYks", sheetNames: ["cab1"] }, (wrong start) `. What do you want to do in your expected result?

Comment: change 1aUoRKCnztsZAvbMwSa8Zk-gB-zfn1KeQnJgWIGRVu24 to 1ShPxDW9qhz4aWgaQ1G9oz7w1yh0-Wfe2VItet95UYks

change sheet

Comment: @dra Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `change 1aUoRKCnztsZAvbMwSa8Zk-gB-zfn1KeQnJgWIGRVu24 to 1ShPxDW9qhz4aWgaQ1G9oz7w1yh0-Wfe2VItet95UYks change sheet`. What do you want to do in your expected result?

Comment: ok finish. I am sorry. already correct. the code is correct, thank you again  
Tanaike